How to change permissions to a file under root?
The folder is mounted into docker container:
docker run --rm -ti \
      -e CGO_ENABLED=0 \
      -e GOFLAGS="-installsuffix=static -trimpath" \
      -v /xxx/wi-api:/src \
      -v /xxx/build/bin:/go/bin \
      -v /xxx/build/tmp/pkg:/go/pkg \
      -v /xxx/build/tmp/cache:/root/.cache \
      xxx/dev-go:1.22 bash -c 'yyy'
...
go: download go1.22.4: chmod /go/pkg/mod/golang.org/toolchain@v0.0.1-go1.22.4.linux-amd64/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/addr2line: permission denied

If I go into container and try to run the command manually I also get errors:
# cd /go/pkg/mod/golang.org/toolchain@v0.0.1-go1.22.4.linux-amd64/pkg/tool/linux_amd64
# chmod 777 *
chmod: changing permissions of 'addr2line': Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of 'asm': Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of 'buildid': Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of 'cgo': Permission denied
...
# ls -la
total 86460
drwxrwxrwx 19 root root      608 Aug 20 12:47 .
dr-xr-xr-x  3 root root       96 Aug 20 12:47 ..
-r--r--r--  1 root root  2438886 Aug 20 12:47 addr2line
-r--r--r--  1 root root  3831435 Aug 20 12:47 asm
-r--r--r--  1 root root  1912930 Aug 20 12:47 buildid
-r--r--r--  1 root root  3740784 Aug 20 12:47 cgo

How to change permission to the files?
UPD
So what I did:

On the host system chmod 244 cgo and in the container this file now looks like -?????????  ? ?    ?           ?            ? cgo. I still have permission denied error if try to chmod 000 cgo or 777.
On the host system chmod 644 cgo and in the container this file now looks like -rw-r--r--  1 root root  3740784 Aug 20 12:47 cgo. I do not have permission denied error if try to chmod 000 cgo or 777.
List item

After 777 this file on a host system looks like -rwxrwxrwx 1 kes staff 3740784 Aug 20 08:47 cgo
After 000 this file on a host system looks like -rw-------  1 kes staff  3740784 Aug 20 08:48 cgo


Stop container. On the host system chmod 600 cgo and after run the container this file now looks ----------  1 root root  3740784 Aug 20 12:47 cgo. I do not have permission denied
Stop container. On the host system chmod 444 cgo and after run the container this file now looks -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3740784 Aug 20 12:47 cgo (I expect the same permissions for this file: -r--r--r--).

In all cases stat shows that inode is different: host Inode: 35731545, container Inode: 57. The values are same for each docker run. The OS is MacOS. In case of Ubuntu 24.04 I have the same Inode on host and container.
Is this how MacOS work? Should I grant some additional permissions to /xxx/build/tmp/pgk folder?
